# PHP infinite loop prevents access to other scripts?

Tags: php, loops, infinite

While running an infinite loop in PHP on Apache, others pages/scripts would hang (take forever to load) until I break execution of the script. However, other pages would still execute on a different user session or browser. Can this be resolved?

Comment: How many CPU's are there in your machine? How many threads are running in apache? I would have thought that multiple scripts would be able to run at the same time, in general. Maybe you need:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html

(I'm assuming your "infinite" is just a "while(1) ;" or some such, and not something more complex that may cause locking conflicts with your main.php)

Comment: Does your infinite script need sessions? If not, you could run it from the command line. Although php might not be the right tool to keep a program running...

Comment: You could try to use a dedicated / special session ID for your infinite running script. Just make sure it cannot clash with your normal session ID's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a race condition problem.

Once you `session_start()` a session, a file attached to the session id is opened with restrictive permissions (locked for reading and writing). If another `session_start()` is called, it will wait for the session file to be unlocked, to avoid the second script to modify asynchronously the session.

Have a look to [this article](http://thwartedefforts.org/2006/11/11/race-conditions-with-ajax-and-php-sessions/) which explain better than me what's happen.

Comment: That's not the definition of a "race condition", it's a simple locked resource. Correct answer though.